# Alterar cor do texto Discord [BOT]

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando alterar a cor do texto após efetuar uma limpeza no chat do Discord. Exemplo:

```
!cclear
```

> (CHAT SUCCESSFULLY CLEANNED!) <-- Aparece na cor verde.

O meu código até o momento:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const pre = '!';

bot.on('message', (Message) =>{

    if(Message.content == pre + 'ping'){
        Message.channel.sendMessage('Pong!');
    }

    if(Message.content == pre + 'cclear'){
        Message.channel.bulkDelete(100);
        Message.channel.sendMessage('Chat successfully cleanned!');
    }

    if(Message.content == pre + 'commands'){
        Message.channel.sendMessage('!cclear [Limpa o chat do canal!]');
        Message.channel.sendMessage('!ping');
        Message.channel.sendMessage('!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Você pode inserir um evento no onclick que altere o valor do css.display para a cor desejada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível enviar mensagens com cores diferentes.
O que eventualmente poderá usar será utilizar Syntax Hightlight para mostrar texto de cores diferentes: https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#syntax-highlighting
O mais perto de verde é utilizando **`css`**

````
```css
Mensagem```
````

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]